# JavaScript Moving First 10 Items From One Options List To Another

Tags: javascript, list, items

I have the following code:

```
function moveAllItems(source, dest)
{
     $("#"+source+" option").appendTo("#"+dest);
}
```

I want this code to append the first 10 items in the source list to the destination list instead of appending all of them at once. Is there a way to do that?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
function moveAllItems(source, dest)
{
     var x = 0;
     while(x < 10){
          $("#"+source".options[i]).appendTo("#"+dest);
          x++;
     }
}
```

but that obviously doesnt work. i have the idea in my head but idk the correct syntax to execute it

Comment: There's a few ways. One simple way would be to use a CSS style `nth-child` selector. Like `option:nth-child(-n+10)`

Comment: how would that look like?

Comment: @Liam OP would like the first 10 items to move from one element to another. They've already made an effort so far. Whilst it may be simple, and may have a dupe, it's a fine question (imo).

Comment: the question is what the correct syntax is @liam

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
function moveItems(n, source, dest) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $("#" + source + " option:eq(" + i + ")").appendTo("#" + dest);
    }
}
```

This will only move n amount of items specified in the first argument of that function.

Comment: what does the :eq part do? is that the way you select the i'th element in HTML?

Comment: okay so that seems to be jquery. tried to run this and the items aren't being moved. i know for a fact theres a correct way of doing this and im starting to think that .appendTo isn't the way to go about it

Comment: @Zeusftw indeed :eq gets the nth element.

Comment: @Zeusftw I made a mistake, try again with the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go about this is via a CSS selector as follows;

```
function moveAllItems(source, dest)
{
     $("#"+source+" option:nth-child(-n+10)").appendTo("#"+dest);
}
```

This will move the first 10 items. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th6ogyo3/) with it working

You can also use the `:eq()` CSS selector and use a loop as you suggested as follows;

```
function moveAllItems(source, dest)
{
     var x = 0;
     while(x < 10){
          $("#"+source+" option:eq("+x+")").appendTo("#"+dest);
          x++;
     }
}
```

The `:eq()` selector, selects the nth element, and so you're moving each item individually in this case. This is probably more hassle than it's worth though.

Comment: Thank you, the first one worked fine. I didn't have any idea until CSS selectors until now time to start reading I guess.

Comment: No worries, CSS selectors are useful to get familiar with, especially when using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following example:

```js
function moveAllItems(source, dest) {
  var x = 0;
  var $src = $('#' + source);
  var $des = $('#' + dest);
  
  while (x < 10) {
    var $opt = $src.find('option').eq(x).clone();
    $des.append($opt);
    x++;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
   <option selected>One</option>
   <option>Two</option>
   <option>Three</option>
   <option>Four</option>
   <option>Five</option>
   <option>Six</option>
   <option>Seven</option>
   <option>Eight</option>
   <option>Nine</option>
   <option>Ten</option>
   <option>Eleven</option>
   <option>Twelve</option>
   <option>Thirteen</option>
   <option>Fourteen</option>
   <option>Fiftheen</option>
</select>
<select id="select2"></select><br />
<input type="button" value="Export" onclick="moveAllItems('select1', 'select2')" />
```